# How to get * DISTINCT rows from a table based on the uniqueness of one particular column?

Tags: mysql

In this table 3 records share the same state value:

```
name | state | country
---------------------
Jake  | NY    | US
Lisa  | PH    | US
Bob   | NY    | US
Jake2 | NY    | US
```

If I use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM myTable
```

The result would be:

```
Jake  | NY    | US
Lisa  | PH    | US
Bob   | NY    | US
Jake2 | NY    | US
```

I need:

```
Jake  | NY    | US
Lisa  | PH    | US
```

How can I get all the distinct rows from a table based on the value of one particular column (state)?

I need

```
Jake  | NY    | US
Lisa  | PH    | 
Bob   | NY    | 
Jake2 | NY    |
```

Comment: So you only want one record from each state to be returned? How do you want it to decide which one?

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: Well asked question.  Are you sure you want * columns?  Why aren't you selecting just `state`?

Comment: @Tom Haws yup needed all columns.

Comment: @JakeRow123, how can Jake and Lisa mean anything when they are nothing more than the (random) first result that happened to have NY in the state column?  I would like to know more about this problem, as it still seems you are abusing MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `Group By`. In this case :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM myTable GROUP BY state
```

Comment: why the -1 ? do u have any better idea ?! shit ah let me guess, the "group by" stmnt...

Answer (score 0):

In the example above, you can't filter on State, as Bob and Jake2 also live in NY; you need some more attributes to define Jake and Lisa as unique.

To get the list of distinct values per state you can simply:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM myTable WHERE State = 'NY'
```

However, as you can see, this will bring back 3 people, and none of them are Lisa.

Comment: just found this article: http://oscarvalles.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/sql-distinct-on-one-column-only/, and tried this: SELECT * FROM myTable GROUP BY state ORDER BY state. This returns the same number of rows as SELECT DISTINCT * from myTable. Which in my table is 216,260. So obviously I can't manually verify if this is correct but judging by the number of returned rows it is. Just wanted to run it by someone knowledgeable to see if this new query is working correctly.

Comment: Yes.  The answer you found is correct.  It isn't classically what I would use GROUP BY for, but it will give you what you need.  What I don't understand is why you don't just use SELECT DISTINCT state from myTable ORDER BY state;

Comment: But even grouping by State will not return just Jake and Lisa - as Bob and Jake2 also belong to State = 'NY'. I agree that GROUP BY is functionally equivalent in this instance though.

Comment: @Tom Haws thanks for verifying. Your query didn't return the right number though, it returned 269,787.

Comment: That means you probably have some duplicate rows which DISTINCT will filter out.

Comment: @JakeRow123- Curioser and curioser.  If you GROUP BY state, you should never get more than 50 results.  If you SELECT DISTINCT state you should never get more than 50 results.  Is that what you want?  Are you merely looking for a list of all the `state` values in use?  Again, we need to understand better what you are trying to do so we can really talk turkey about how to properly design the data and the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think FGraviton is close, but I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY state
```

The DISTINCT is not needed for the result you want.  On the other hand, I might prefer this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT state 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY state;
```

Again, we need to understand better what you are trying to do so we can really talk turkey about how to properly design the data and the query.

Now, keep in mind that the answer by dash would return all the unique variations on rows that happen to have 'NY' as their state.  In other words, conceivably (in fact, probably ideally, assuming good design and data integrity) you will not weed out a single row with the DISTINCT * in this example, because every row will (should/may?) have some type of variation, probably in the name column.  Again, the DISTINCT * and the WHERE state = 'NY' clause do not talk to each other.  The DISTINCT is only going to do a distinct on the result of the query.  DISTINCT has no way of knowing that you want distinct states only.

The MySQL docs say that DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 is equivalent to GROUP BY c1, c2, c3.

I'm sure we can help you if we can somehow figure out what you are trying to do.

Thanks for the additional information you gave.  Based on that additional information, here's what I would do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM geo_locations 
WHERE city = 'CITYNAMEHERE' 
GROUP BY city, latitude, longitude
ORDER BY city ASC;
```

Of course that assumes that every city has a single One True lat/lon.  If that's in doubt, you may need to round your lat/lon in your GROUP BY clause something like this.

```
SELECT *, round 
FROM geo_locations 
WHERE city = 'CITYNAMEHERE' 
GROUP BY city, round(latitude, 2), round(longitude, 2)
ORDER BY city ASC;
```

Comment: Ok so basically I am using the maxmind geo database. In the locations table there are lots of duplicate records. The only difference is the auto incremented primary key. I needed to display all the cities that belong to a particular country. But just selecting from that table using the country code in the where clause would give me all the duplicates. You are right about how the distinct flag alone would merely give me the 1st occurrence of a city found by that name. Some countries have multiple different cities with the same name. So the answer I chose above didn't do it. cont...

Comment: instead I am now using "SELECT * FROM geo_locations WHERE city = 'CITYNAMEHERE' GROUP BY latitude ORDER BY city ASC. <-- this treats 2 cities as distinct even if they share the same name since their latitudes are different, while at the same time prevent completely duplicate rows from appearing. I know it's not full proof because there is a rare chance that 2 cities with the same name can have the same latitude but different longitude. But that would be very rare. Unless I'm missing something this should do it.

Comment: You are doing a good job so far.  I would only add to group by latitude, longitude